Can I connect the HDD to the RAID controller so that the size of the virtual disk remains the same?
I have a WD20EZAZ 2TB disk with important data, connected to a server with an LSI MegaRAID SAS 9260-4i controller and an Asus P9D-I motherboard. Also I have another disks. I configured all connected disks as individual RAID0 arrays to use them as separate devices.
New disks work fine, but the existing disk with data fail to mount.
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/d2tb2

Failed to read last sector (3907024894): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.

I noticed that the number of sectors on the disk is smaller when connected through the MegaRAID controller compared to connecting directly to a SATA port on the motherboard.
fdisk -l output when connected through MegaRAID:
Disk /dev/sdc: 1.82 TiB, 1998998994944 bytes, 3904294912 sectors
Disk model: MR9260-4i
...
/dev/sdc1        2048 3907026943 3907024896  1.8T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

fdisk -l output when connected directly to the motherboard's SATA port:
Disk /dev/sdc: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD20EZAZ-00L
...
/dev/sdc1        2048 3907026943 3907024896  1.8T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

The RAID controller reduces the available sectors, which makes the disk size ~1.3 GB smaller (2734256 sectors difference).
I have tried exploring the MegaRAID BIOS utility for settings that might allow direct passthrough (mapping the physical disk to the virtual disk without any modifications to the sector count).
Question:
How can I configure the RAID controller to reflect the physical disk without changes in sector count so that the NTFS partition remains mountable? Is it possible to avoid size reduction caused by MegaRAID? Or would it be better to connect all disks directly to the motherboard's SATA ports in this case?

You need to use a plain SAS/SATA controller/HBA to access the full disk. The RAID controller hides its metadata/superblock from the host. If it has touched the disk, previous data may have been overwritten.

I hope that the RAID controller has not written a lot of its data to the disk )). Now I have connected the disk directly to the sata port on the motherboard. There are a lot of files on the disk, so I will hardly be able to determine whether there is damage among some of them.

Virtual disks will always have different size, because any RAID members reserve some space to store a RAID metadata which explains what is this disk and in what activity it participates.
MegaRAID SAS has a nice feature: a "jbod" mode switch, which will make it behave as if it was a "fancy HBA". It gives a direct access to the disks (this is what you really want), though, only those which have no RAID metadata that controller recognizes as its own; valid RAID members would continue to be omitted and valid LDs will still be presented as usual.
This is a proper way of using individual disks, instead of making all disks RAID0.
Sometimes, this feature is disabled or unsupported by your version of the card firmware, in that case you'd need to update it. Or, you can reflash the card with the "IT" firmware, then it will lose its ability to be a RAID adapter and become a "true HBA".
You can find this switch either in the card configuration UI available at the keystroke during boot, or configure it from the OS, using a control utility MegaCLI or the newer utility StorCLI, though your card is quite old and I think MegaCLI would be more appropriate. You can download MegaCLI and StorCLI on the Broadcom web site for your OS. Firmware updates can also be found there. And, don't forget to download a utility manual there, it's a big PDF and it explains how to use it.
There is also a DEB repository at hwraid.le-vert.net that has MegaCLI, and StorCLI is available in the HPE SDR MCP which also has a DEB repository.
With MegaCLI, you first enable the mode:
megacli -AdpSetProp -EnableJBOD 1 -a0

Then you choose disks and put them into Unconfigured Good state:
megacli  -pdmakegood -physdrv [252:0,252:1,252:2,252:3,252:4,252:5] -force –a0

(list your disks with megacli -pdlist -a0 and RAIDs with megacli -ldpdinfo -a0)
Then you may change Unconfigured Good disks into JBOD:
megacli  -pdmakejbod -physdrv [252:0,252:1,252:2,252:3,252:4,252:5] –a0

I strongly recommend to always have a control utility installed and that the staff who manages the server must be comfortable using it. It's the way to monitor the HW RAID while OS is running. RAID doesn't help you without proper management, monitoring and alerting!
